# AWS EC2: why is cloud-init ignoring my script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-init

I have asked this before, and I thought that I had solved it ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57956914/why-is-my-cloud-init-script-not-getting-run)), but now it no longer works.

I'm setting up an EC2 instance with terraform:

```
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami = "${var.image}"
  instance_type = "${var.inst_type}"
  key_name = "Some Keys"
  subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.jan_public_subnet.id}"
  user_data = "${file("${path.module}/test")}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    "${aws_security_group.jan_vpc_security_group.id}"
  ]
  tags={
    Name="${var.inst_name}"
  }
}
```

And the test file (in `user_data`) is:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat >/var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-once/test <<!
runcmd:
  - mkdir /run/test-per-once
!
chmod 755 /var/lib/cloud/scripts/per-once/test
```

I can see that the instructions in `test` are carried out - the file gets created and it has the permissions as specified. But cloud-init ignores it - this is what I see in `/var/log/cloud-init.log`

```
2019-09-27 15:25:01,110 - stages.py[DEBUG]: Running module scripts-per-once (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_per_once' from '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_per_once.py'>) with frequency once
2019-09-27 15:25:01,110 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: start: modules-final/config-scripts-per-once: running config-scripts-per-once with frequency once
2019-09-27 15:25:01,110 - util.py[DEBUG]: Writing to /var/lib/cloud/sem/config_scripts_per_once.once - wb: [420] 24 bytes
2019-09-27 15:25:01,110 - helpers.py[DEBUG]: Running config-scripts-per-once using lock (<FileLock using file '/var/lib/cloud/sem/config_scripts_per_once.once'>)
2019-09-27 15:25:01,110 - handlers.py[DEBUG]: finish: modules-final/config-scripts-per-once: SUCCESS: config-scripts-per-once ran successfully
```

I can only assume that I am doing something wrong - but what?

Comment: Is this a custom ami?

Comment: no: ami-2ef21649 and ami-014b778c196908102 both do this to me :-)